# Вывести документ Excel на сайте

Tags: php, wordpress

Как вывести документ Excel на сайте? Документ имеет большую таблицу.

Answer (score 0):

прочитать его через https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet, и как таблицу отобразить на сайте